# How improve temperature sensitivity of HP 721A DC Power Supply voltage reference?

Tags: power-supply, zener, buffer, voltage-reference, emitter-follower

I have a sentimental affection for my HP 721A DC Power Supply:
http://hpmemoryproject.org/pict/wall_a/anim/721a_q90/viewer.htm

Rugged, dependable, and roughly as old as I am, it is also pretty temperature sensitive. At the high end of its voltage output (30V), it can easily drift 700mV from morning turn-on (~19C) to the late afternoon heat (~25C).

I believe this is primarily due to the primitive-ish emitter-follower-based voltage reference circuit is uses:

[image: 721A Voltage Reference circuit]

(full schematic here: http://www.kennethkuhn.com/hpmuseum/scans/hp721a_sch.gif)

`V.ref` is -V.zener + V.BE of the Germanium PNP (Q4) and has a temperature variance of roughly 26,000 ppm over the course of the day's temperature variations.

I was thinking to submit one of my five specimens to experimental surgery to see if I could improve the temperature sensitivity without disrupting the rest of the circuit. (The sentimental affection I mentioned combined with low eBay prices have ended with me "adopting" a number of these units :)

No need for excessive precision; a circuit with a TC in the hundreds of ppm would be a huge improvement. I'd like something with discrete components if it would work with say two or three transistors. I'm also considering a highish-precision low-voltage reference (~1.22V) buffered with an LM358 op amp with gain of about 6, but wanted to avoid the possible need for compensation gymnastics if a simple-ish discrete circuit would give the improvement I'm looking for.

What options might one recommend?

Comment: Lovely clean power supply in the animation, They can certainly be useful bench units and a bunch will be pretty flexible. If I had to try something simple I would replace the zenner and following transistor with modern parts, adding a second zenner pre-regulator would allow for less current variation in the main zenner and increasing the transistor gain would reduce the zenner load change.

Comment: While I don't have a solution, I'm pretty sure a preregulator on the zener won't help. My understanding is that it's leakage in the transistor that's the problem.

Comment: As I understand the problem so far, the forward drop on the emitter-base junction (nominally 200mV since it's Germanium) has a temperature coefficient (TC) of a few mV per degree C, and that this combined with the TC of the zener is producing the variation in the reference voltage. The temperature I mentioned is the ambient, but the junction temperature could be substantially higher.

Comment: Regarding the zener current, it's quite stable at roughly 300µA. I'm not sure there's much that can be done there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe replace Q4 and the reference diode with a super-cheap (pennies in quantity) TO-92 [TL431](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm431.pdf) and two 1% resistors set up to maintain the -6.9V voltage where the emitter of Q4 is connected. The 560R resistor can stay if it is 1/4 W or better, just remove Q4

Resistors would be something like 4.99K and 2.80K.

In other words, connect a shunt regulator between 0V and -6.9V nodes, and use the existing 560R resistor to pass 16mA through the shunt regulator. It will typically drift about 50ppm/°C. (the 560R resistor will be on the other side compared to the below schematic)

[image]

Of course there are much better shunt regulators available but I'm not sure the difference would be worth it.

Comment: Thanks @Spehro, this definitely sounds like the hot ticket, I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes :)  I see I can get these at Jameco for about ten cents each, so I'm going to order some up and drive over there :)  I think I might bump up the 560R resistor to 1.5K or whatever will give me about 6mA through the R19, R20/21 branch, just to keep it about the same as originally. I'm excited about this! I might even be able to mount it all up on the existing PCB!

Answer (score 3):

**Outcome Report**

The approach @Spehro suggested worked out very well, producing a *very* stiff voltage reference (for literally 10 cents worth of parts) which I programmed with R1 and R2 to roughly 7.5V. The specific value is not critical as there is a trimming pot in the circuit that calibrates the supply to the value used.

The schematic of the replacement looks like this:
[image]

I was able to install it on the original circuit board, basically as a replacement for CR7, the original zener diode:

[image]

Q4 and R22 were removed. R23 was replaced with a somewhat larger value to maintain the original current through the output voltage sampling circuit. The now-empty emitter and base connections for Q4 were shorted with a wire to complete the circuit.

I wired up the LM431 "sub-circuit" in a 2 x 5 hole piece of prototyping PCB:

[image]

The reference voltage is now as solid as a rock, having at most 2mV drift between 25C and 50C inside case temperature. The original drifted 135mV for the same temperature range. So this is a massive improvement in stability.

The bad news is that the temperature sensitivity of the overall supply is very much improved, but still drifts by easily a few hundred millivolts, somewhat depending on load and output voltage; about 40% of the original drift. So there's more work to do.

It looks like the remaining temperature sensitivity is coming from the emitter-base PN junction in Q3, the voltage drop of which determines the effective error amp sense point. That PN junction voltage drop varies between 0.18 and 0.12V. Since it is outside the feedback loop that shift in sample voltage changes the output by roughly 7mV/mv.

But that's a topic for a separate question. Thanks again @Spehro for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide detailed feedback!

Comment: My pleasure @Spehro, my modest efforts were more than repaid by the time your guidance saved me from going down blind alleys :)